# LISTAGG with Clob Values and problem with ora-31013

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to simulate listagg functionality for CLOB values. I have source codes for one "ETL" stored in Oracle db table. For this purpose, we can call this column as "source_code". It has CLOB data type (because of potential long varchars).

I need to create new view or table above this table, that will "group" source codes to one new grouped value eg. whole_source_code. It should be grouped by etl_name.

It should look like:

```
SELECT etl_name, LISTAGG(source_code, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY source_code_id) AS SQL_CODE
FROM ETL_TABLE
GROUP BY etl_name;
```

I tried this but it does not work because of ORA-31013:

```
SELECT etl_name, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, source_code, '; ').EXTRACT('//TEXT()') ORDER BY source_code_id).GETCLOBVAL(),',') AS SQL_CODE
FROM ETL_TABLE
GROUP BY etl_name;
```

**I don't know, why I getting this error.**
Can you help?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times. If you think the first question should be reopened then edit that question to make it clear why it is not a duplicate (and if necessary, refine the question to ask a single focused question) and then leave a comment asking for it to be reopened.